# react useCallback not updating function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Isn't the hook `useCallback` supposed to return an updated function every time a dependency change?

I wrote this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-drake-qj3b5?file=/src/App.js) trying to reduce the problem I'm facing in my real app to the minimum reproducible example.

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const fields = [
  {
    name: "first_name",
    onSubmitTransformer: (x) => "",
    defaultValue: ""
  },
  {
    name: "last_name",
    onSubmitTransformer: (x) => x.replace("0", ""),
    defaultValue: ""
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [instance, setInstance] = useState(
    fields.reduce(
      (acc, { name, defaultValue }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: defaultValue }),
      {}
    )
  );

  const onChange = (name, e) =>
    setInstance((instance) => ({ ...instance, [name]: e.target.value }));

  const validate = useCallback(() => {
    Object.entries(instance).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (v === "") {
        console.log("error while validating", k, "value cannot be empty");
      }
    });
  }, [instance]);

  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      setInstance((instance) =>
        fields.reduce(
          (acc, { name, onSubmitTransformer }) => ({
            ...acc,
            [name]: onSubmitTransformer(acc[name])
          }),
          instance
        )
      );
      validate();
    },
    [validate]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {fields.map(({ name }) => (
          <input
            key={`field_${name}`}
            placeholder={name}
            value={instance[name]}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(name, e)}
          />
        ))}

        <button type="submit">Create object</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my code. Basically it renders a form based on `fields`. Fields is a list of objects containing characteristics of the field. Among characteristic there one called `onSubmitTransformer` that is applied when user submit the form. When user submit the form after tranforming values, a validation is performed. I wrapped `validate` inside a `useCallback` hook because it uses `instance` value that is changed right before by transform function.

*To test the code sandbox example please type something is first_name input field and submit.*

*Expected behaviour would be to see in the console the error log statement for first_name as transformer is going to change it to ''.*

**Problem is `validate` seems to not update properly.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like an issue with understanding how React lifecycle works. Calling `setInstance` will not update `instance` immediately, instead `instance` will be updated on the next render. Similarly, `validate` will not update until the next render. So within your `onSubmit` function, you trigger a rerender by calling `setInstance`, but then run `validate` using the value of `instance` at the *beginning* of this render (before the `onSubmitTransformer` functions have run).

A simple way to fix this is to refactor `validate` so that it accepts a value for `instance` instead of using the one from state directly. Then transform the values on `instance` outside of `setInstance`.

Here's an example:

```
function App() {
    // setup

    const validate = useCallback((instance) => {
        // validate as usual
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        const transformedInstance = fields.reduce((acc, {name, onSubmitTransformer}) => ({
            ...acc,
            [name]: onSubmitTransformer(acc[name]),
        }), instance);
        setInstance(transformedInstance);
        validate(transformedInstance);
    }, [instance, validate]);

    // rest of component
}
```

Now the only worry might be using a stale version of `instance` (which could happen if `instance` is updated and `onSubmit` is called in the same render). If you're concerned about this, you could add a ref value for `instance` and use that for submission and validation. This way would be a bit closer to your current code.

Here's an alternate example using that approach:

```
function App() {
    const [instance, setInstance] = useState(/* ... */);

    const instanceRef = useRef(instance);
    useEffect(() => {
        instanceRef.current = instance;
    }, [instance]);

    const validate = useCallback(() => {
        Object.entries(instanceRef.current).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v === "") {
              console.log("error while validating", k, "value cannot be empty");
            }
          });
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        const transformedInstance = fields.reduce((acc, {name, onSubmitTransformer}) => ({
            ...acc,
            [name]: onSubmitTransformer(acc[name]),
        }), instanceRef.current);
        setInstance(transformedInstance);
        validate(transformedInstance);
    }, [validate]);

    // rest of component
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer and the high quality of content. I thought that although updated instance would get rendered in DOM in the next render, the instance accessed by methods (at least with useCallback hook) would be updated, but I was wrong.